# how to get value from jquery in dynamic input

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a questions with answer or 
multiple choice in **CodeIgniter**, I create the choice using jQuery and now I don't know how to get all value from text input.

can someone help me for this case??

**This code:**

```js
var choices = [{
  id_soal: 'choice1'
}, {
  id_soal: 'choice2'
}, {
  id_soal: 'choice3'
}];
var html = '';
var i;
for (i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
  html += '<div class="row">',
    html += '<div class="col-xs-8 col-md-4>',
    html += '<div class="input-group">',
    html += '<span class="input-group-addon" style="background:green"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>  Soal' + (i + 1) + '</span>',
    html += '<input type="text" name="Question' + i + '" id="Question' + i + '" class="Question form-control" placeholder="Question" required>',
    html += '</div></div></div></br>',

    html += '<div class="row">',
    html += '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">',
    html += '<div class="input-group">',
    html += '<span class="input-group-addon">A</span>',
    html += '<input type="text" name="A_jawaban' + i + '" id="A_jawaban' + i + '" class="form-control A_jawaban" placeholder="Result" required>',
    html += '</div></div>'
  html += '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">',
    html += '<div class="input-group">',
    html += '<span class="input-group-addon">  B</span>',
    html += '<input type="text" name="B_jawaban' + i + '" id="B_jawaban' + i + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Result" required>',
    html += '</div></div>',
    html += '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-4">',
    html += '<div class="input-group">',
    html += '<span class="input-group-addon">  C</span>',
    html += '<input type="text" name="C_jawaban' + i + '" id="C_jawaban' + i + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Result" required>',
    html += '</div></div></div><br>';

  html += '<div class="row">',
    html += '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6">',
    html += '<div class="input-group">',
    html += '<span class="input-group-addon">  D</span>',
    html += '<input type="text" name="D_jawaban' + i + '" id="D_jawaban' + i + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Result" required>',
    html += '</div></div>'
  html += '<div class="col-xs-4 col-md-6">',
    html += '<div class="input-group">',
    html += '<span class="input-group-addon">  E</span>',
    html += '<input type="text" name="E_jawaban' + i + '" id="E_jawaban' + i + '" class="form-control" placeholder="Result" required>',
    html += '</div></div></div><br>';
}
$('.judul').html(html);

$('#tambah').click(function(event) {

  console.log('THIS CHOICES',choices)
  var results = $('.Question').serializeArray();
  console.log('FOR QUESTIONS',results)
var resultsAnswearA = $('.A_jawaban').serializeArray();
  console.log('FOR QUESTIONS',resultsAnswearA)




})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div name="judul" class="judul"></div>

  <button id="tambah" name="tambah" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="icon-pencil5"></i> Tambah</button>
```

**UPDATE**

wow sorry for my question above, I forgot and just realized I got the answer to use query selector. just check the code

Comment: Your input name is not `Question`, it begins with `Question + i`. You can use `$( "input[name^='Question']" )` selector and a loop.

Comment: hey thanks for comment and help, i get the point just like `$('.Question').serializeArray();`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var allInputsValue = {};

$(".judul input").each(function(){
    //Add each input value to all inputs
    allInputsValue[allInputsValue.length] = {
        "name":$(this).attr("name"),
        "value":$(this).val()
    };
});

console.log(allInputsValue);
```

Comment: hey thanks for comment and help to write the code for me, i get the point just like `$('.Question').serializeArray()`